# Disabling mouse events on 'div'

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I have an interesting problem in disabling mouse events using the 'pointer-events' css styling.

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rethna2/e4CMf/). It has a parent and two children div, and I make 'pointer-events' as 'none' to one of the children. If I click on that div, its mouse listeners are not triggered (this is expected) but mouse events of its parent div is triggered.

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
   console.log("Parent clicked"); 
});
```

How to disable mouse events on the parent div, if I clicked on its children which are disabled for mouse events?

One option is to filter using an "if" condition on the parent click. But i don't need it, as I want to listen for mouse events on 'divs' present behind the parent.

Please provide some help :)

thanks,
Rethna

Comment: So you want to listen mouse event of only one child in parent div ?

Comment: Setting `pointer-events` to none does not necessarily mean an element will never receive mouse events. If a child element permits capture, it will receive those events as they bubble up the parent chain.

Comment: Ideally my expectation is, if I set 'pointer-events' as 'none', then it should be invisible for mouse events. If i click on it, it should not trigger the events on its parent too.

Comment: You can't do that with css pointer events. Since the #child2 has its pointer event disabled, the browser just triggers the click event of #child2's parent.

Comment: @Rethna if you keep that logic, then the parent of child2's parent all the way up to the body shouldn't trigger the click event.

Answer (score 14):

I couldnt make the pointer-events work as I intended, so I changed the javascript in order to achieve what you wanted.
What i did was to event.stopPropagation on the child2, so you can click him and only fire his click event, not his parent's click event.
By the way, i know little about jquery, so I wrote a mixed beetwen pure javascript and jquery, hope someone can help me translate that.

Here comes the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4CMf/1/)

CSS:

```
#child1{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#child2{
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#parent{
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('child1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log("child1 clicked");
    }, false);
    
    document.getElementById('child2').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        console.log("child2 clicked");
    }, false);
    
    document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log("Parent clicked");
    }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this post, here's something very useful..

el.setPointerCapture() will focus all pointer events on given element.

not only do you isolate the node, but also gain a lot of performance as the browser stops performing hittests on anything else